# Meson and OpenCV: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, meson-build

I was using this guide to build OpenCV from the source.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Now I am using meson to build and compile my project.
I am trying to use 2 different methods to include OpenCV in my project and **both ways work**.

Method 1:

`cv2 = dependency('OpenCV', method: 'cmake')`

Method 2:

`cv2 = dependency('opencv4', required: true)`

when I compile with meson I get:

```
Dependency opencv4 found: YES 4.6.0 (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/bgsegm.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/calib3d.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp" : YES (cached)
Has header "opencv4/opencv2/video.hpp" : YES (cached)
```

which is great.

finally I am using:

```
lala = executable('lala','lala.cpp',
                    c_args : args,
                    include_directories : [includes_lala],
                    dependencies : [some_deps,cv2],
                    cpp_args : ['-g','-ggdb'],
                    link_with  : some_lib )
```

but I am getting the next following error:

```
In file included from ../src/lala.cpp:1:
../include/lala.hpp:16:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
   16 | #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I didn't find any solution. thanks!

Comment: Could you show result of $ pkg-config --cflags opencv4 ?

Comment: And try #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: <> or "" only affect lookup order, not success. -- figure out what "include directories" you're giving the compiler. the pkg-config result should contain that

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I missed one of the executable files that should include the OpenCV dependency too.

`dependencies : [somestuff,cv2]`

thanks for the help!